# Is the beast in Revelation 19, a man?

Tags: life-of-jesus, eschatology, war, beast

Scripture says that Jesus will make war on the enemies of God from a horse and his sword will be the word of his mouth. It looks like the devil will lead an army of men into a war against Jesus' headquarters here on earth after the 1000 year reign in the air.

**NB**

It's **not the devil who leads**, **it's the beast**. The beast is the one who attempts to lead an invasion against Jesus' camp of Saints. This is because during this time the devil is imprisoned in the abyss, and that's why later he is freed

### The Rider on a White Horse

**Revelation 19:11-15**

> Then I saw heaven opened, and behold, a white horse! The one sitting on it is called Faithful and True, and in righteousness he judges and makes war. His eyes are like a flame of fire, and on his head are many diadems, and he has a name written that no one knows but himself. He is clothed in a robe dipped in blood, and the name by which he is called is The Word of God. And the armies of heaven, arrayed in fine linen, white and pure, were following him on white horses.

Heaven has an army and Jesus is the leader.

### Birds get ready to feed on the flesh of fallen men

**Revelation 19:17**

> Then I saw an angel standing in the sun, and with a loud voice he called to all the birds that fly directly overhead, “Come, gather for the great supper of God, to eat the flesh of kings, the flesh of captains, the flesh of mighty men, the flesh of horses and their riders, and the flesh of all men, both free and slave, both small and great.”

The size of fallen men is going to be so huge that the birds are called to feast on the remains.

### The Beast and the nations get ready for war against Jesus and his armies

**Revelation 19:19**

> And I saw the beast and the kings of the earth with their armies gathered to make war against him who was sitting on the horse and against his army.

Both sides get ready to attack

### Jesus Defeats the Beast and captures  him

**Revelation 19:20**

> And the beast was captured, and with it the false prophet who in its presence had done the signs by which he deceived those who had received the mark of the beast and those who worshiped its image. These two were thrown alive into the lake of fire that burns with sulfur.

The beast loses the war to Jesus, he is captured and thrown alive into the lake of fire.

Since this beast is alive and thrown alongside the false prophet into the lake of fire, does it follow that the beast is a **human king** and the false prophet his priest?

Using the **principal of duality** like truth and lies, angels and demons,  God and devil then it follows that the beast is the opposite of Christ in form in that Christ has a physical body and the Spirit of God so does this beast has a physical body and the Spirit of Satan over his head?

### Close Examination of the Throwing into the Lake of Fire Verse

I have also examined the verse that describes the act of throwing and the Bible says as if these were two men being thrown alive into the lake of fire

**Revelation 19:20**

> ...These two were thrown alive into the lake of fire that burns with sulfur.

**These two were thrown** sounds as if the false prophet and the beast are both equal in form and other attributes

Comment: Do you take the descriptions in Revelation chapter 19 as literal or symbolic and spiritual?  Likewise, with Jesus' headquarters and the 1,000 year reign?

Comment: @Lesley , some I take them as literal like the war, the war is literal as even the birds are alerted but the beast, it's got to be a man because he and the false prophet are thrown alive into the lake of fire

Comment: Thanks for explaining, although not every Christian thinks the beast and the false prophet are literal men.

Comment: @Lesley, But the beast is the opposite of Jesus using the principal of duality

Comment: This is a classic example of an "opinion-based" question. Such questions can be answered by summarizing various schools of thought objectively. But when it comes to the Book of Revelation, objectivity is rare.

Answer (score 2):

In v20, the "false prophet" is described as someone who works "in the presence of" the beast, working signs to deceive those who receive the mark and worship the image of the beast. This is exactly what the "beast from the land" does in ch13 vv12-17. So I would regard the false prophet and the earth-beast as the same person, renamed.

That leaves "the beast from the sea" as the "beast" of ch19.

I regard the beast from the sea and the beast from the land as, respectively, the domineering state and the leader of that state. Empire and Emperor.

P.S. Now that the question has been changed, it is necessary to add that I have been answering the original question "Is the beast of ch19 the sea-beast or the earth beast of ch13?" Otherwise, the reader is left with the impression that I was missing the point.

Comment: How can the false prophet work signs in the presence of the beast and be him at the same time?

Comment: Because he is the second beast, and he is working signs in the presence of the first beast. The whole point of this question is that (in ch13) we are talking about two different entities called "beast".

Comment: Yes but is he a man? Or is it the image that is caused to speak?

Comment: Yes, I would identify the second beast, also called "the false prophet", as a man.

Comment: But the Bible says the sea beast is there, then the earth beast(false prophet) causes the earth inhabitants to make an image and then causes it to speak and then this image gives an order for no trade without his mark makes sense

Comment: So who is the sea beast according to your opinion?

Comment: As I said, I regard the sea-beast as the domineering state, on the precedent of the beasts from the sea in Daniel ch7. Compare the relationship between Hitler and the nazi Reich; he exercised the authority of the Reich "in its presence", and in his speeches ("false prophet") he caused his audience to worship the Reich. He even enforced the use of identity marks (the swastika and the Nazi salute), and used the "boycotting" weapon on a class of people he wanted to reject.

Comment: You draw a parallel to the third Reich and their fuhrer, exercised authority of the first beast in its presence, very tough to beat

Answer (score 0):

Consider that symbolically:

- Beasts represent military/political powers, or their leaders.
- Women represent religious organizations.

And the false prophet is obviously a religious leader.

> does this beast have a physical body and the Spirit of Satan over his head?

That would make sense if the beast is a powerful dictator, directly influenced by Satan.

> These two were thrown sounds as if the false prophet and the beast are both equal in form and other attributes

That too would make sense if the false prophet is the head of a great religious organization.

80 years ago, Hitler (possessed by a demon?) and the Pope would have been good candidates for these positions.
One might consider that as a small-scale preview of what is yet to come.

Revelation 17:7 depicts the woman riding the beast, clearly meaning that the Church appears to be controlling the State.

Coincidentally, consider what the emblem of the European Union is, a woman riding a bull (search for "EU statue").